# How to Visually Depict a Stack in Memory?

Tags: debugging, gdb

This is a two-part question:

1. I was wondering if anyone knew of any FREE tools/applications to design visual applications of memory stacks?  Of which would include stack information (e.g. stack pointers, return addresses, variables, frame pointers...).  I've heard Multi (Green Hills) might do this, but when I've checked their website it didn't seem as if they offered such a feature.  If you can't think of a program that can do what I'm asking, then I would benefit from the best image you can find that includes stack information (I've Googled "memory stack images," but they are all very different looking).
2. I'm completely new to the C programming language and am trying to do the above.  As such, a consequence of my first question is how do I find out all the stack information for me to put into a visual format?  I'm doing this for a class assignment and believe that GDB might be able to accomplish this.  I'm still learning how to use GDB (have read a couple of guides already), so if anyone knows how to use it to find out all the variables, return addresses, pointers, and so forth for each step in a program executing through each stack frame, that would be awesome.  If you know another tool that can accomplish this simply however, then I'd be open to hearing about it and how to use it.

Thanks so much!

Note:  I found some similar questions addressed on this site, but must of them either weren't answered or were vaguely answered.  I hope someone out there has a few minutes to detail an explanation, particularly for question 2.

Operating System:  Linux (Ubuntu)
Programming Language:  C

Answer (score 0):

A couple of points:

- Basically you need a means to walk the stack
- This is very platform dependent and it depends on the os and the hardware platform you are using. It looks like you are using linux. For windows there are native API's available
- I assume this is for c programs, so you need to understand the C calling conventions (how are the parameters are put on the stack, where the return address is stored and so on
- In addition there might be additional difficulties if ASLR is active.
- For linux several APIs exist. One of them is

[http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~bart/DynStackwalker.pdf][1]

Comment: Apologies for the limited information.

Operating System:  Linux (Ubuntu)
Programming Language:  C

In short I need a way to utilize GDB (or another program) to "walk the stack" as you said.  The DynStackwalker you recommended though appears to require modification of the C code?  It's my endeavor to walk the stack without making any modification to the code.